# Сократить код до одного return

Tags: java, циклы, return

Мне нужна помощь в сокращении кода. В общем, имеется 2 массива A и B, а также число V, которое является элементом массива A. Наша задача найти индекс числа V в массиве A и вывести число под найденным индексом в массиве B. Если что-то непонятно - спрашивайте! НО мне нужно использовать ТОЛЬКО ОДИН RETURN. Вот с этим возникли проблемы(

```
public class upr8zad3DOP {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 7, 0, 2134, 321, 321};
        int[] b = {5, 6, 21, 7, 12, 6, 88563};
        int v = 2134;
        System.out.println(findIndex(a, v, b));
    }

    public static int findIndex(int arr[], int t, int arr2[]) {
        int i = 0;
        if (arr == null) {
            i = -1;
        }
        int len = arr.length;
        while (i < len) {
            if (arr[i] == t) {
                return arr2[i];
            } else {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
       return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему в функции поиска индекса возвращается значение по индексу: `return arr2[i];` ?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Потому что мне как-то надо вернуть элемент массива arr2 с индексом i. Вот здесь у меня использован 1 return. А в конце кода еще один. А мне по задаче можно использовать только один return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один `return`:

```
public static int findIndex(int arr[], int t, int arr2[]) {
    int index = -1;

    if (arr != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == t) {
                index = arr2[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Вы очень мне помогли)

Comment: Зачем использовать тернарный оператор? Разве не проще будет в цикле при совпадении написать : index = arr2[i];  и в конце: return index; . Тогда значение index будет либо равно значению из arr2[] при совпадении, либо -1, которым инициализировали в начале метода

Comment: @pavlofff, вы правы, поправил

Comment: @Дмитрий, немного отрефакторил ответ, прошу посмотреть

Comment: @pavlofff, ага :) пора отдыхать )